# Pyramid integration over hypercube via diagonal

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute a specific integral over the unit hypercube ($x_i=[0,1]$ with $i=1..d$), $\int dV F(\mathbf{x}) $.

Measuring the diagonal ($D$) towards a corner from the center (1/2), I think the volume enclosed is:

$$V = \left(\frac{2D}{\sqrt{d}}\right)^d $$

This is because given a side length, the diagonal is $\sqrt{d}$ times longer, and we need to include the side lengths in both directions (x2) from the center.

Now I define $F(D)=D^{-d}$, as the function I want to integrate. This function increases towards the center of the hypercube. In fact, the integral would not converge. So the function I want to integrate is $F(D)=D^{-d}$ until D becomes so small that $F(D_{min})=e^{-100}$ (which implies $D_{min}=e^{-100/d}$), at which point $F(D)=e^{-100}$ is constant for $D<D_{min}$.

Here is my attempt:

$$Z=\int  F(\mathbf{x}) dV=\int F(\mathbf{x})  \frac{dV}{dD} dD = \int  D^{-d} C \cdot D^d \cdot  dD$$

with $C=2^d \cdot \sqrt{d}^{-d}$.

Canceling some terms and breaking into before/after $D_{min}$ is reached:

$$Z=\int_{D_{min}}^{1/2} C dD + \int_{0}^{D_{min}} F(D_{min}) \frac{dV}{dD} dD =C \int_{D_{min}}^{1/2} dD + C \int_{0}^{D_{min}} D_{min}^d \cdot e^{100} dD  $$

integrating out (first part is trivial, for the second the function is flat too):

$$Z = \left({1\over2} - D_{min} + e^{100}e^{-100}\right) C \approx {3\over2} 2^d \cdot \sqrt{d}^{-d}  $$

However, I think this is incorrect. When I apply a complex numerical integration algorithm, which should be accurate to those small scales (zooming in essentially), I get $Z\approx{3\over2}\cdot2^d\cdot 8$ for $d=2..16$, and no $\sqrt{d}^{-d}$ increase.

**Why am I off by a factor of 8?**

I suspect I either made a mistake with the dV/dD, or with integrating half or the full cube?

---

**Edit 1: Second attempt**

If the V formula is correct, then

$$\frac{dV}{dD} = C \cdot (d+1) D^{d-1}$$

now with $C=2^d \cdot \sqrt{d}^{-d+1}$.

$$Z=\int  D^{-d} C \cdot D^{d-1} \cdot  dD = 
\int_{D_{min}}^{1\over2} C D^{-1} dD + \int_{0}^{D_{min}} F(D_{min}) \frac{dV}{dD} dD = 
C \left(\log{\sqrt{d}\over2} - \log(D_{min}) + e^{100} \cdot D_{min}^d \right) =
C \left(\log{\sqrt{d}\over2} + 100/d + 1/d\right) $$

This also shows an normalisation and dependency on d that is incompatible with the numerical results.

Comment: Your $dV/dD$ is definitely wrong.

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks, I tried again (see Edit 1)

Comment: If $V = 2^d d^{-d/2} D^d$ as you wrote, then $dV/dD = 2^d d^{1 - d/2} D^{d-1}$. I assume what you have in edit 1 is a typo. // Secondly, if you are integrating over the diagonal, the upper bound of your integration is not 1/2, but $\sqrt{d}/2$, but this seems to have been incorporated when you plugged into the result.

Comment: In terms of the $\sqrt{d}$ difference: are you sure your numerical algorithm is integrating the correct thing? In other words, are you keying in your $F$ appropriately? If there is a difference in a factor of $\sqrt{d}$ in what you chose $F$ to be, this could easily make up the difference.